# How can I load images in Next.js only after the necessary data has been rendered on the page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading

Currently, I have a Home component that receives data from an API and renders it on the page, but I don't want to load all the images at once, as it says that data for page "/"  exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance. I want to load images after the page is rendered. Can someone provide a solution or point me in the right direction? Here is the code for my Home component:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.scss";
import MainCard from "../components/MainCard";
import NormalCard from "../components/NormalCard";
import { News } from "../types/types";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { listEng } from "./category/[category]";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const LastNews = dynamic(() => import("../components/LastNews"), { ssr: false });
const NewsBlock = dynamic(() => import("../components/NewsBlock"), { ssr: false });
type Props = {
 lastFivePosts: News[];
 topThreeRatedPosts: News[];
 postsByCategory: News[];
};

export default function Home({lastFivePosts, topThreeRatedPosts, postsByCategory}:   Props) {

if (!lastFivePosts && !topThreeRatedPosts) {
return <div>Ведутся технічні роботи</div>;
}

return (
<div className={styles.wrap}>
  <div className={styles.upper_block}>
    <div className={styles.leftBlock}>
      <NormalCard news={lastFivePosts[1]} />
      <NormalCard news={lastFivePosts[2]} />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.middleBlock}>
      <MainCard news={lastFivePosts[0]} />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.rightBlock}>
      <NormalCard news={lastFivePosts[3]} />
      <NormalCard news={lastFivePosts[4]} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr className={styles.hrHome} />
  <div className={styles.titlePopular}>
    <h1>Вибір редакції</h1>
    <span>
      Тут ми зібрали три найкращі новини за останній час на розсуд нашої
      редакції. Наші журналісти працюють наполегливо, щоб надавати вам
      найактуальнішу та найцікавішу інформацію з усього світу.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.lastNewsBlock}>
    <div className={styles.lastNews}>
      <LastNews items={topThreeRatedPosts} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.newsBlock}>
    {listEng.map((category, index) => (
      <NewsBlock news={postsByCategory} key={index} category={category} />
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
);
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
let res = null;
try {
res = await axios.get(
  `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_CONNECT_URL}/api/news`
);
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}
return {
props: {
  lastFivePosts: res?.data.lastFivePosts,
  topThreeRatedPosts: res?.data.topThreeRatedPosts,
  postsByCategory: res?.data.postsByCategory,
},
};
};
```

Here is my API

```
import dbConnect from "../../../utils/dbConnect";
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from "next";
import NewsPosts from "../../../models/NewsPosts";


export default async function handler(req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse){
const {method} = req
await dbConnect()

switch (method) {
    case "GET":
        try {
            
            const lastFivePosts = await NewsPosts.find({}, { title: 1, _id: 1, createdAt: 1, category: 1 })
                .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
                .limit(5);
           
            
            const topThreeRatedPosts = await NewsPosts.find(
                { rating: { $gte: 0, $lte: 9 }, published: true },
                { title: 1, _id: 1, createdAt: 1, category: 1, description: 1 }
            )
                .sort({ rating: -1 })
                .limit(3);
          
            const postsByCategory = await NewsPosts.aggregate([
                { $match: { published: true } },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$category',
                        posts: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        category: '$_id',
                        posts: {
                            $slice: [
                                {
                                    $map: {
                                        input: '$posts',
                                        as: 'post',
                                        in: {
                                            _id: '$$post._id',
                                            title: '$$post.title',
                                            // image: '$$post.image',
                                            createdAt: '$$post.createdAt',
                                            category: '$_id'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                10
                            ]
                        },
                        count: 1
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: '$posts' },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$posts' } }
            ]);
            const news = {
                lastFivePosts,
                topThreeRatedPosts,
                postsByCategory
            }
            
            res.status(200).json(news)
        }catch (e:any) {
            res.status(500).json(e)
        }
        break;
    case "POST":
        try {
            const newsCreate = await NewsPosts.create(req.body)
            res.status(201).json(newsCreate)
        }catch (e: any) {
            res.status(500).json(e)
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Comment: Would [this](https://dev.to/dephraiim/lazy-loading-images-in-nextjs-3am8#:~:text=Lazy%20loading%20is%20enabled%20by,or%20may%20not%20be%20required.) article help?

Comment: @Luke no, I think that is not what I'm looking for, because in this case images are already fetched from api, and response exceeds the threshold